Docker build command failed
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

Dockerfile with above content failing with error message on build creation.
=> ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                                                                                 0.8s

[internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest:


Dockerfile:1
1 | >>> FROM ubuntu
2 |     RUN apt-get update
3 |     RUN apt-get install -y python3
ERROR: failed to solve: ubuntu: error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: no usernames for https://index.docker.io/v1/``
docker build . -t hello

Can you add the error-message?

Consider using the python base image if that's an option for you.  Don't forget to set a CMD to run the application when the container starts.  It's possible to hit Docker layer-caching issues if you rebuild this image, and you may need to RUN apt-get update && apt-get install in a single command.

I solved this issue by following steps

rm ~/.docker/config.json

login docker login command in terminal and


